# Does there exist any navigation package except the ROS navigation?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does there exist any navigation package except the ROS navigation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225600/does-there-exist-any-navigation-package-except-the-ros-navigation?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) on 2016-02-02**:
The answer is "yes". However, whether you'll find a good package, it's depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For indoor navigation and autonomous exploration there is http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d .

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0